# How to change a line chart series's color according to the point's value in Kendo UI?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-dataviz

For example, I have a series which have 5 points and their values are 5,10,15,20,25, now I want to change the color of the part series which contains point1(value:5) to point2(value:10) to be red, and want to change the color of the part series which contains point2(value:10) to point2(value:15) to be green, and so on, How to do that? Now I can change the color of the whole series, but do not know how to change the part of the series according to its value?

**change the whole series**

```
function onDataBound(e) {
    e.sender.options.series[0].color= "red";   
}
```

Just like this example, I now can change the color of the point, but can not change the line between the start point and end point.[my example](http://jsfiddle.net/whoamiwho/EE22M/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [color](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/dataviz/chart#configuration-series.color) option of the series can be set to a function which will be called during rendering. Here is a short demo:

```
<div id="chart"></div>
<script>
$("#chart").kendoChart({
  series: [{
    data: [1, 2],
    color: function(point) {
      if (point.value > 1) {
        return "red";
      }

      // use the default series theme color
    }
  }]
});
```

Comment: It seems it only change the color of the point,but not change the line   series between the two point.What I want is not only the point,but also the line series between the point.

Comment: I want to do similar to @flower, not just the color of the dot, i want to change the color of the line between those regions.